# flutter error: (dynamic) => Null is not a subtype of (String, dynamic)

Tags: flutter

Here is the error I am getting,

```
[ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(199)] 
Unhandled Exception: type '(dynamic) => Null' is not a 
          subtype of type '(String, dynamic) => void' of 'f'
The getter 'vendorDocList' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: vendorDocList
```

Code:

```
class VendorsDocument {
  String lead_id;
  Future<getVendorsDoc> getVendorDocList(lead_id) async {
    final response  = await http.post(Uri.parse('example.com/vendor_doc'),
        headers:{
          'Accept': 'application/json',
          HttpHeaders.authorizationHeader: 'Bearer $accessToken}',
        },
        body: {'lead_id':'$lead_id'});
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      // print(response.body);
      return getVendorsDoc.fromJson( json.decode(response.body) );
    } else {
      throw Exception('No records found');
    }
  }

}
class getVendorsDoc {
  bool status;
  String msg;
  List<VendorDocList> vendorDocList;

  getVendorsDoc({this.status, this.msg, this.vendorDocList});

  getVendorsDoc.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    status = json['status'];
    msg = json['message'];
    vendorDocList = new List<VendorDocList>();
    json['data'].forEach((v) {
      vendorDocList.add(new VendorDocList.fromJson(v));
    });
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['status'] = this.status;
    data['message'] = this.msg;
    // if (this.vendorDocList != null) {
      data['data'] = this.vendorDocList.map((v) => v.toJson()).toList();
    // }
    return data;
  }
}

class VendorDocList {
  String logo;

  VendorDocList(
      {this.logo});

  VendorDocList.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    logo = json['logo'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['logo'] = this.logo;
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi. Welcome to SO. `Please help me to resolve this issue` is not a good title for a post. I changed it, please check if it ok to you.

Answer (score 1):

```
Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['logo'] = this.logo;
  }
```

check this toJson method in the VendorDocList class, you are only assigning the logo to the data['logo'] without returning anything, which is why the mapping function returns null.

you should return the data like this:

```
Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['logo'] = this.logo;
return data;
  }
```